# drag and drop environment to start developing in gwt

Tags: eclipse, gwt, netbeans, smartgwt, gwt-widgets

is there any drag and drop environment to work with GWT widgets.
or any user friendly IDE or plugin on IDE's 
i remember using some thing like MyEclips for developing Hibernate was better then working with .xml files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eclipse-based [WindowBuilder Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/) supports GWT and is now free, courtesy of Google.

Comment: That link seems to be broken. Try this https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/

Answer (score 1):

I tried GWT Designer, http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/index.html, but I think for now I'll stick to code the guis myself by hand.

The main reasons are:

- Sometimes, it takes a little while (longer than I can wait) to load the design mode.
- Sometimes it breaks after you modify code underneath.
- Sometimes, does not do what you expect it to do.

I would suggest you giving it a try and see if it works out for your needs.

In my opinion, the experience using it has been frustrating than encouraging.